# frm-92101 there was a failure in the forms server during startup

Tags: oracleforms, oas

Oracle Application Server 10g
Operating System: Unix

I got the below error:

frm-92101 there was a failure in the forms server during startup

The solution in windows as follow:
control panel ( Middle tier) , click on the OPMN for middle tier -> LOG ON ->
Check Allow Service to Interact with Desktop

How can I apply the above solution in UNIX?

Comment: First google result is https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2393027 which points you to try: $`opmnctl status`, then check the `application.log` and `formsstd.out` files for errors.

Answer (score 1):

missing rpm openmotif21-2.1.30-11.EL5.i386.rpm on Linux OS.

[Project downloads](https://oss.oracle.com/projects/compat-oracle/files/Enterprise_Linux/)